# Arcpy Code result- "NaN"

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, layers

When i run this code (in arcView 10.3) in order to check the data frame extent, i received "NaN NaN" result with the exact data frame. I don't understand why python print this out?
I checked in http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/dataframe-class.htm but didn't find any answer.

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"D:\desktop\Project\project.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,'*')[0]
print df.name
print df.extent
mxd.save()
del mxd
```

The result is:

```
>>> 
Layers
126169.249888028 611217.599085453 149776.35592577 627939.29919552 NaN NaN NaN NaN
>>>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you get the NaN-values is the following.
If you look at the extent properties, described on the following page http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/extent.htm, you see the object has four more properties. These properties aren't set by default, so you'll get the NaN 'error'.

If you only want to display the XMin, YMin, XMax & YMax values you need to replace `print df.extent` with the following:

```
print str(df.extent.XMin)+ " " + str(df.extent.YMin) + " " + str(df.extent.XMax) + " " + str(df.extent.YMax)
```